# Как определить, содержит ли url определенное слово?

Tags: jquery, url, javascript

Доброго всем дня.

Такой вопрос, в js есть `location.pathname`, который возвращает из url путь, к примеру:

`/каталог/название-раздела-каталога/товар`

Как можно определить на js, что данный путь содержит слово "каталог"? То есть я хочу понять, что в данный момент я в каталоге.

**Обновление**

Фишка в чем: пути могут быть разными, мне из строки `/слово/слово1/слово2` нужно узнать, в каком каталоге я нахожусь, но я не могу знать, какого вида будет url и на каком месте будет стоять данное нужное мне слово, то есть нужен своеобразный поиск по строке, если можно так выразиться.

Comment: Будет проще понять, если приведете примеры исходных строк и значений, которые должна возвращать функция на эти строки.

Answer (score 1):

`location.pathname.indexOf('string')`

Answer (score 0):

[str.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Может, я не сильно понятно объяснил, сори. Обновил вопрос.